# Что нужно знать о Вебсокетах чтобы писать сложные приложения

Tags: websocket

Насколько мне известно использовать AJAX уже неуместно (разве что в тех случаях когда не нужно постоянно мониторить статистику чего либо и информация по времени не особо важна)

Что делать когда допустим нужно реализовать приложение, которое будет в разных частях реализовываться на сокетах, тот же самый интернет ресурс где важно видеть есть ли человек в сети или нету, пишет ли он тебе в чат или нет, оставил ли он тебе на стене запись или нет (да, грубо говоря это пример вк)

Так вот что нужно знать о сокетах, чтобы можно было спокойно писать сетевые приложения любой сложности? Какая литература для этого потребуется?

P.S Товарищи которые проголосовали за закрытие вопроса, что именно вас не устраивает? Я написал конкретный вопрос! Что не так то?

Comment: По мне так факта, что по открытому сокету в любой момент времени можно передать нужную информацию в любом направлении более чем достаточно для разработки любого приложения.

Comment: @Mike Ну а как же знания как открывать, закрывать, передавать информацию и вообще сетевое строение знать?

Comment: А это уже легко гуглится в процессе работы :)

Comment: @MaximPro, а вот на этот вопрос без явного указания языка программирования вам никто ничего не подскажет. Да и как вам подсказал Mike, чуть ли не для любого языка программирования найти ответ на ваш вопрос вы сможете без особых проблем с помощью Гугла, например, на том же Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mike Да плохо что-то гуглится есть одна мана `Самоучитель игры на WINSOCK` но от нее толку мало знаний по факту нет чтобы так углубленно, так поверхносто

Comment: @terron А ну ка примеры со стаковерфлоу?! Что-то я не нашел

Comment: @MaximPro Стоп. а причем тут winsock, вы же писали про websocket. это две большие разницы !

Comment: @Mike Так а функции и принцип схожий =) Но если честно мне сокеты под пыху нужны, все таки веб...учить Node.JS не хочу времени уйма. Я знаю что можно на php написать, а вот документации кроме офф сайта маловато...да и про сокеты хотелось бы побольше узнать принцип и механику, так сказать быть в курсе дела

Comment: @MaximPro тогда возвращаемся к вопросу о языке. хотя сейчас на большинство языков есть библиотеки. А лучше именно с библиотекой, что бы велосипеды не изобретать реализуя протокол websocket.

Comment: @Mike Так я написал что язык php. Есть Ratchet, но хочется свой сервер написать =)

Comment: PHP не очень дружит с websccket, хотя есть и неплохие решения, но по большей части они напоминают костыли. хорошо с ws работают сервера на java. но помимо прочего есть одна фишка у ws - он предназначен для передачи текстовых или бинарных данных. и с этим он справляется великолепно. но просто передать эти данные мало, надо их как-то сформировать, чтоб обе стороны их нормально понимали. можно json, но кпд данные/трафик будет малым. пока стандартных решений нет, но я думаю , со временем предложат красивое решени.

Comment: @Вадим Что значит не дружит? Если бы она не дружила то не было бы раздела Sockets в PHP. Просто этим никто не занимался и интерфейс функций кстати очень похож на C

Comment: @MaximPro для ws желательно многопоточное выполнение , в php для этого используют demon.  и пр.

Comment: @Вадим Ммм, да ладно! А то я без вас не знал! Только вот литературу бы подходящую найти и практические примеры! А не пустословить, хорошо?!

Comment: @MaximPro по литературе: лучшего чем https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets я не нашёл. ну по практике - имею приличный опыт и есть интересные решения, серверная часть на java, ну а по клиентской - обращайся , помогу.

Comment: @Вадим По клиентской части там делать нечего! Интересует именно серверная часть. Да и вообще интересует разносторонняя реализация сокетов. То есть не только синхронные

Comment: @MaximPro могу дать рекомендации по использованию, есть наработка про самому процессу работы с ws. если сможешь реализовать это на сервере - будет красиво.

Comment: @Вадим Наработки чего и где (клиент? сервер?)?

Comment: @MaximPro наработки всего цикла. но если у  тебя сервер не на java , то только сам обмен и клиент(браузер). на клиенте ничего сложного нет, но универсализм и простота.  реализация на сервере уж твоя.

Comment: @Вадим В наработках не нуждаюсь, либо сам либо никак =)

Comment: @MaximPro дак я это и не предлагаю, просто идея использования. а я б не отказался , если помогли улучшить, свежие мысли они всегда хорошо.

Comment: @Вадим Поверьте, как использовать я точно придумаю, а вот от толковой документации точно бы никто не отказался, жаль что таковые отсутствуют